# composition of continuous and bounded uniformly continuous functions.

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $f: R \to R$ continuous, $h: S \to R$ bounded and uniformly continuous. Prove that $f(h(x))$ is uniformly continuous.

My rough intuition and attempt at this problem are as below:
Fix $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta>0$ not depending on y such that when $\lvert x-y \rvert < \delta$, we have $\lvert h(x)-h(y) \rvert < \epsilon$

Now, for f(h(x)) to be uniformly continuous, we need $\lvert f(h(x))-f(h(y)) \rvert < \epsilon'$, when $\lvert h(x)-h(y) \rvert < \epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ does not depend on $h(y)$.
Since f(x) is continuous we have the former claim and need to prove the latter only.
But as h(x) is bounded, we can fix $\epsilon$ so small such that $\lvert h(x)-h(y) \rvert < \epsilon$ is always true and thus $\epsilon$ does not depend on $h(y)$.

This is probably false but I just want to give it a try. Can someone give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)? Because $h$ is bounded, $f$ is actually uniformly continuous on the range of $f$, so we're just showing a composition of two uniformly continuous functions are uniformly continuous.

Comment: Do you mean f is uniformly continuous on the range of f or h?

Comment: @TheoBendit But $h(S)$ may not be closed, hence not compact.

Comment: @sucksatmath I meant the range of $h$, sorry.

Comment: @Kaind Sure, but $\overline{h(S)}$ is closed and bounded, and hence compact, and hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\overline{h(S)}$, which implies uniform continuity on any subset including $h(S)$.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot the latter property. +1.